# How do I find the average color of an image?

Tags: image-processing, color

It sounds so simple to do, but the best solution I've found so far is by using the `MeanFilter` function, which isn't really feasible on large images. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are [`ImageMeasurements`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageMeasurements.html) for this:

```
ImageMeasurements[image, "Mean"]
(* {0.427958, 0.559264, 0.130725} *)
```

Answer (score 7):

If `ImageMeasurements` didn't exist we could have used this one-liner:

```
Total[#]/Length[#] &@Flatten[ImageData[img], 1]
```

`ImageData` will give you a matrix of RGB vectors, `Flatten[...,1]` will then give you a one-dimensional list of RGB vectors. `Total` adds them together, by dividing by the number of RGB vectors we get the mean.

Also take a look at blochwave's version in his comment below.

Comment: What about `Mean[#] &@Flatten[ImageData[image], 1]`?

Comment: @blochwave Hah! In my desire to do something more low level I missed this intermediate version. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: Cool! I didn't know about the `ImageData` function, but it makes perfect sense now.